# How do I make a dropdown menu in html?

Tags: javascript, css, html

[website preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8vG1.jpg)I'm having trouble inserting a rolldown menu into the navigation bar on my website's html code. I have tried various options but non of them seems to work. Any idea?

I want to make the "button" a rolldown which I indicated with "ROLLDOWN" in the code.

```html
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Option1</a></li>
    <li><a href="park.html">Option2</a></li>
    <li><a href="jatekok.html"> <font color="#d30000">ROLLDOWN</font></a></li>
    <li><a href="szolgaltatasok.html">Option3</a></li>
    <li><a href="kapcsolat.html">Option4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So what should happen which that would be clicked. And its not button its anchor tag

Comment: What do you mean by "rolldown" ... like a sub menu? Can you please include your most previous attempt that didn't work? fyi `<font>` tag is deprecated you should stop using it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want all the options inline?

Comment: I want to create a rolldown/dropdown menu which appears when the user moves the mouse over the element. Yes, like a sub menu or something. @MaheerAli

Comment: ` <div class="dropdown">
  <li class="dropbtn">Dropdown</li>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>` 
@zgood this is what i have tried. What do you recommend using instead of <font>?

Comment: You can use a `<span>` with a class instead of the `<font>` tag. then just add that class on the span to your stylesheet and add your color style there. update your question with your best attempt... include CSS and HTML

Answer (score 1):

Is it helpful:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .symbol {
        font-family: Symbola;
    }
    #dropDown {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #DCCDCD;
        width: 115px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
    #dropDownTitle {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #dropDownItems {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#E5E2E2;
        left: 0;
        top: 100%;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    #dropDownItems > div {
        padding: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #dropDownItems > div:hover {
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="dropDown">
        <div id="dropDownTitle">Click Here <span class="symbol">▼</span></div>
        <div id="dropDownItems" style="transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(0)">
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>Item 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var dropDownj = document.getElementById("dropDown");
        var dropDownTitlej = document.getElementById("dropDownTitle");
        var dropDownItemsj = document.getElementById("dropDownItems");
        dropDownTitlej.onclick = function() {
            if (dropDownItemsj.style.transform !== "translateY(-50%) scaleY(0)") {
                dropDownItemsj.style.transform = "translateY(-50%) scaleY(0)"
            } else {
                dropDownItemsj.style.transform = "translateY(0) scaleY(1)";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmKomL)**

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you'd need to style it but this will give you the functionality of the dropdown.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Option1</a></li>
    <li><a href="park.html">Option2</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><p class="dropdown">ROLLDOWN</p>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    </div>
   </li>
    <li><a href="szolgaltatasok.html">Option3</a></li>
    <li><a href="kapcsolat.html">Option4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```